# How do I count the number of rows that have different dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the total numbers of row in SQL database.

"tableA" :

```
   id | date       | 
   ---+------------+
    1 | 2019-09-03 | 
    2 | 2019-09-03 | 
    3 | 2019-09-04 | 
    4 | 2019-09-05 |
```

I want to execute it as new column name "total" that should have like this :

```
 total
 -----
   3
```

because they are 3 different dates.

I know that the result must use 2 query like this:

```
SELECT date 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY date AS total;

SELECT COUNT(total) 
FROM tableA;
```

How to combine 2 queries like that or there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(distinct date)`

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct date) FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count( distinct date) as total from tableA;
```

Comment: the result is not what i want. but thankyou for suggesting me.

Comment: @FauzanZharfan why is this answer wrong ? It is exactly same as the accepted answer.

Comment: oh it works thankyou man. sorry, i think i am copy the wrong text before.